# Program to find shortest distance from f(x) to origin

Tags: python, minimize

In Python (3.8) I try make a script that takes a function `f(x)` as input, e.g;

```
f(x) = 1/x
```

If we define the define `y = f(x)`, as a line on the euclidean space, we can calculate the distance `d()` from the origin `(0,0)` for each point `(x,f(x))` on the line as;

```
d(x,y) = sqrt(x^2+(f(x))^2)
```

My goal is to find the `x` such that the above distance is minimised. This can be done by solving

```
2x+2f(x)*f'(x) = 0
```

I will be grateful for help. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what the y is. you have d(x,y) but dont see a y in your distance expression.. is y = f(x) ?

Comment: https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html can both give the derivative and solve to 0, would you consider that as an option? Let me know if you need an example

Comment: I am very new beginner and if you can give give examples to read a function, to deriverte and solve the solution, is perfect. Or you could please use f(x)=1/x see how it works for that example. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Example in `sympy` (not expert on `sympy`);

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers import solve

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')

g = 1/x

h = 2*x + (2*g) * (diff(g,x))

solve(h,x)
```

This will return `[-1, 1, -I, I]` so `-1` and `1` should be real answers;

```
distance = x**2 + g**2

distance.subs(x,1)
distance.subs(x,-1)
```

I did not `sqrt()` in distance, but I hope you get an idea how this could be solved in `sympy` . This is 1 way, there are package to approximate the derivative, and find  roots,  which should also work.